# How to add twitter capability to my struts2 application

Tags: struts2, twitter, twitter-oauth

I developed struts2 web application, now I want people to login from their twitter account, so I need to place a button called "Login with Twitter" under my normal login button. I already did Facebook integration so as far as my knowledge we need to create the application first in twitter so i did that then i am confused what to do, please anyone guide me through that steps.

Comment: I've done facebook and twitter, if you figure out google that would be great.

Comment: i gave up my heart and soul but i was not able to get it done, please help me.

Comment: Let me know where you are stuck but the code following is a more less complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really recall the process of registering your application with twitter but google "Single-Sign-On (SSO) using twitter".

First you need to register your application, in doing so you will be given a consumer_key and a consumer_secret (not sure if those are twitters terms).

Then the process is to send the user to twitter using those credentials, have the user sign in and then have twitter return control back to your application with a callback. That callback will contain an authorization token, which will grant access to twitter services so we will save that in the session.

After you have registered your application the following code will perform login, and let you post the string "hello!" to your twitter account (Assuming the application has this privilege).

**TwitterGrantAccess.java**

```
package com.quaternion.demo.action.twitter;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.builder.api.TwitterApi;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

@Results(value = {
    @Result(name = "success", location = "${authorizationURL}", type = "redirect"),
    @Result(name = "error", location = "/WEB-INF/content/error.jsp")
})
public class TwitterGrantAccess extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String authorizationURL = null;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        //Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        String consumer_key = "NOT_PUTTING_MY_KEY_ON_STACK_OVERFLOW!";
        String consumer_secret = "NOT_PUTTING_MY_CONSUMER_SECRET_ON_STACK_OVERFLOW!";

        OAuthService twitterService = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                .apiKey(consumer_key)
                .apiSecret(consumer_secret)
                .callback("http://localhost:8080/demo/twitter/twitter-callback")
                .build();
        Token requestToken = twitterService.getRequestToken();
        authorizationURL = twitterService.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        session.put("twitterService", twitterService);
        session.put("requestToken", requestToken);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getAuthorizationURL() {
        return this.authorizationURL;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.session = map;
    }
}
```

The Callback invoked by twitter (something you will not call as a user)...
**TwitterCallback.java**

```
package com.quaternion.demo.action.twitter;



import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

@Results(value = {
    @Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/content/twitter/twitter-callback-success.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "error", location = "/WEB-INF/content/twitter/twitter-callback-error.jsp")
})
public class TwitterCallback extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String key;
    private String secret;
    //returned from twitter
    private String oauth_token;
    private String oauth_verifier;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        if (session.containsKey("accessToken") && session.get("accessToken") != null) {
            return SUCCESS; //accessToken already exists!
        }
        Token requestToken = (Token) session.get("requestToken");
        if (objectToken == null) {
            super.addActionError("requestToken is null");
            return ERROR;
        }
        OAuthService twitterService = (OAuthService) session.get("twitterService");
        System.out.println(requestToken.toString());
        System.out.println(this.getOauth_verifier());
        //Token accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, this.getOauth_verifier());
        Token accessToken = twitterService.getAccessToken(requestToken, new Verifier(this.getOauth_verifier()));
        session.put("accessToken", accessToken);
        this.setKey(accessToken.getToken()); //just to see something happen
        this.setSecret(accessToken.getSecret());//just to see something happen
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.session = map;
    }

    /**
     * @return the key
     */
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    /**
     * @param key the key to set
     */
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String getOauth_token() {
        return oauth_token;
    }

    /**
     * @param oauth_token the oauth_token to set
     */
    public void setOauth_token(String oauth_token) {
        this.oauth_token = oauth_token;
    }

    public String getOauth_verifier() {
        return oauth_verifier;
    }


    public void setOauth_verifier(String oauth_verifier) {
        this.oauth_verifier = oauth_verifier;
    }
}
```

With this done your application can now use the API, let's post a tweet:

**Tweet.java**

```
//Posts the string "hello!" to the users twitter feed then redirects to
//ken_mcwilliams twitter url, because that is the account I will be
//logging into... change you your own account during development 

package com.quaternion.demo.action.twitter;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

@Results({
    @Result(name = "success", location = "https://twitter.com/#!/ken_mcwilliams", type = "redirect")
})
public class Tweet extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String status;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        Token accessToken = (Token) session.get("accessToken");
        OAuthService twitterService = (OAuthService) session.get("twitterService");
        String url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?status=";
        String twitterStatus;
        if (status == null || status.isEmpty() == true) {
            twitterStatus = "hello!";
        }else{
            twitterStatus = status;
        }

        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url + twitterStatus);
        twitterService.signRequest(accessToken, request); // the access token from step 4
        Response response = request.send();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        session = map;
    }
}
```

PS: twitter-callback-success.jsp and twitter-callback-error.jsp don't contain anything interesting, they just state "You now have access to twitter and everything is great!" and "Something went horribly wrong".

Comment: Oh and this was tested to work as of today. This was just some quick demo code, test the hell out of it if you're going to use it.

Comment: thank you so much sir, but i need to login through twitter to my web application using struts2, can it be done?

Comment: please do not mind, i am new to java so i am having tough time to understand that code that you sent. Please explain me how can i implement in my struts2 project as sign in with twitter to login to my project

Comment: The code only requires a basic struts2-project with the struts2-conventions-plugin... the imports have been posted so you could figure out the dependencies I would recommend creating a new struts2 project, then you just call the "twitter-grant-access" action followed by the "tweet" action. As mentioned you will need to register your application with twitter to get a valid consumer_key and consumer_secret.